# macOS bash globbing quoted variable unexpectedly

Tags: bash, macos, variables, glob, quoting

On Linux with bash 5.2.15, single quotes prevent globbing as expected:

### Good

```
$ dir='/path?/to?/file?'; echo $dir
/path?/to?/file?
$
```

However, on macOS with bash 3.2.57, I get this undesirable behavior:

### Bad

```
$ dir='/path?/to?/file?'; echo $dir

$
```

This unintended globbing appears to occur in the echo command, as the variable is set correctly:

```
$ set | grep ^dir
dir='/path?/to?/file?'
```

I guess this unintended globbing is a bug in the ancient bash version on macOS. I tried setting noglob to no avail. Can you think of a workaround to get the Good behavior above?

Comment: You must have a non-default configuration for this to happen -- by default, globs that don't match anything expand to the glob expression itself. Which is to say -- it's not necessarily true that this has _anything to do_ with quoting; it looks much more like a difference in the `nullglob` setting.

Comment: Note that if you want to ensure there's no globbing run, you want `echo "$dir"`, not `echo $dir`. This is covered in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else); because the globbing you want to suppress is performed at expansion time rather than assignment time, quotes on _assignment_ make no difference.

Comment: BTW, you can use `shopt -p nullglob` to print the current nullglob setting; if that outputs `shopt -s nullglob` it tells you the flag is set, if it outputs `shopt -u nullglob` it tells you that it's unset; you can run either of those to _force_ it to the appropriate (set or unset) state.

Comment: Also, see ["When to wrap \[double-\]quotes around a shell variable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) (short answer: almost always).

Comment: Not reproducible on my Mac. Both bash versions behave the same for me. Make sure that you have configured them identically; otherwise you are comparing apple with pears.

Comment: I concur that my question is a duplicate of the one cited. Sadly, my initial searches did not find it. @CharlesDuffy: You are correct. My ancient .bashrc on macOS set nullglob; it is unset in my Linux environment. I see I "fixed" it there in 2021 as it broke completion for me. I Thanks, all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the variable in the echo works:

```
$ dir=/path?/to?/file?; echo "$dir"
/path?/to?/file?
```

As it turns out, quotes aren't needed when setting the variable.

This now begs the question as to why the unquoted echo works on Linux without quoting.

Comment: Did I not answer that question (aside: [_raised_ not _begged_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beg_the_question#English)) in a comment on the question itself? (For a glob to expand to nothing you must have the `nullglob` flag set; by default, globs with no matches expand back to the glob expression itself).